# Bootstrap carousel caption buttons are not clickable

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im building a page with bootstrap carousel which has caption of paragraph and two buttons, buttons are not appearing as clickable, when clicked nothing happens.

```html
{% block body %}

<div id ="car-container">
<div class="container-fluid" style= "padding-right: 0px;
    padding-left: 0px;">



<div id="carousel-home" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div id  = "carousel-inner">

    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <div class = "overlay-background">
    <div class="overlay">
      <img  class="d-block w-100 carousel-home-img" src="empImg1.jpg" alt="First slide">
     
</div>
    </div>
     <div id = "cap_one"  class="carousel-caption ">
     <div id = "cap-head">
    <h5 id ="h5">The People Award</h5>
    </div>
    <p> We have been awarded ‘The People Award’ three years running due to our high levels of customer service.</p>
    
   <a href="{{ path('emp_services_lettings') }}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-md"   role="button" style = "background-color:  #2b459c!important; color: #FFFFFF!important">Find a property</a>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-md" style = "background-color:  #d39e00!important; color: #FFFFFF!important">Valuation</button>
  </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

for your button to be clickable you need to add an onclick event, like so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-md"
style="background-color:  #d39e00!important; color: #FFFFFF!important" 
onclick="testMe()">Valuation</button>
```

and in your javascript create a `function testMe(){ code you want to execute when clicked }`

as for you href tag, I am not sure what variables you are using to create the path, so it's a little difficult to follow, but you can just put the path like so:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" // and the rest of your code
```

Comment: I was able to resolve it by changing the zindex of the caption element, you answer provides good solution for someone who wants achieve the goal  using JavaScript. Thank you.